# Is this question mark placement correct: "You've never heard 'Dancing Queen'?"

Tags: punctuation

Would the question mark come after the single quotation mark and before the double quotation mark? Like this:

> "You've never heard 'Dancing Queen'?"

This is dialogue in fiction, so the double quotations are necessary I believe. According to grammarly and numerous other sources, shorter works like songs go in quotes, whereas a longer piece like an album would be italicized. So is this question mark placement correct? Or is there another way to format?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, quotations inside a quotation will devolve to single quote marks. This may be a typo in your original post, but you actually have a double-quote to the left of the word Dancing:

> "You've never heard "Dancing Queen'?"

It would be correctly punctuated thus:

> "You've never heard 'Dancing Queen'?"

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to *Italicize* the title in this context.   Either way, it doesn't come off looking great and there's regional differences as to whether the punctuation comes before or after the final quote... and whether you should use double or single quotes first.   At best, leave the single quotes for quotes within quotes.

Comment: From what I've seen, it's not correct to italicize in this case? "In general, you should italicize the titles of long works, like books, movies, or record albums. Use quotation marks for the titles of shorter pieces of work: poems, articles, book chapters, songs, T.V. episodes, etc." (from Grammarly)